# How to Hyperlink Buttons on Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

How is it possible to hyperlink a button on a android application. this is my code can you please edit it and then reply as it is very needed my app is in a short time limit
        `<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="GTA 3" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind an `onClickListener` to your button. Put this in your activity:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Do 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));      
startActivity(intent);
If you want to open a web browser in //do your stuff here

Comment: @sean correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you need to include the protocol too (http or https), otherwise `parse()` will throw an exception.